# Array in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with an array - list in flutter, I get the posts in the below function and after I want to add the images in other array (one posts maybe will have 1 or more images)

```
  List posts = [];
  List searchPosts = [];
  List imagesPosts = [];

   _loadPosts() async{
   await Network().getDataPosts('post/getallposts?page=1').then((res) {
    var posts1 = jsonDecode(res.body);
    print(posts1);
    posts = posts1['data']['data'];
    setState(() {  
      posts = searchPosts = posts1['data']['data']; 
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < searchPosts.length; i++) {
        imagesPosts.add(searchPosts[i]['photos_name']);
    }
    print(imagesPosts);

    for (var i = 0; i < searchPosts.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < imagesPosts[i].length; j++) {
        print(imagesPosts[j]);
      }
    }


   },
   onError: (error) {
    print(error);
   });
  }
```

Api response

```
"success": true,
    "data": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 254,
                "title": "Abc",
                "comments": "sdsadasdasd",
                "photos_name": "[\"2019_11_18_11_14_07_0000001574075647_cdv_photo_026.jpg\",\"2019_11_18_11_14_08_0000001574075648_cdv_photo_027.jpg\"]",
                "lat": 37.96604,
                "longt": 23.732739,
                "created_at": "2019-11-22 16:28:42",
                "updated_at": "2019-11-22 16:28:43",
                "userid": "1",
                "rate": 3,


                }
            },
```

I get this error
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..4, inclusive: 5

I get posts from API , posts contains post name, comments , images name
In the imagesPosts at the end I have the below

```
[["2019_11_18_11_14_07_0000001574075647_cdv_photo_026.jpg","2019_11_18_11_14_08_0000001574075648_cdv_photo_027.jpg"], ["2019_11_19_11_22_20_0000001574162540_cdv_photo_005.jpg"], ["2019_11_19_11_15_43_0000001574162143_cdv_photo_004.jpg"], ["2019_11_19_10_46_53_0000001574160413_cdv_photo_003.jpg"], ["2019_11_19_10_45_07_0000001574160307_cdv_photo_002.jpg"]]
```

I think my issue is here

```
for (var i = 0; i < searchPosts.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < imagesPosts[i].length; j++) {
        print(imagesPosts[j]);
      }
    }
```

When I remove this is working fine but I cannot get imagesPosts

I want to display the images here

```
  for (int i = 0; i <  searchPosts.length; i++) {
  ...
  for (var j = 0; j < imagesPosts[i].length; j++)
                         Image.network("http://127.0.0.1:8004/images/"+searchPosts[i]['userid']+"/"+imagesPosts[j]),
SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
```

I am new in flutter...

Comment: i supposed showing your ```res.body``` could attract more help.

Comment: yes correct, I updated the original post